# Ajax post and redirect?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I know this question has been asked in various forms, but I'm very new to ajax and php and I was hoping for some help. I have a JS function that takes a passed variable that I'd like to post to a new page and then go to that page. However I'm not sure how to post to the next page then go to the page and get the data.

For example: my function takes a course name, I'd like to post the name to the new page and then redirect to the new page and assign the data to a textbox. Here's what I've tried:

```
 function clickLogo(val){
            console.log(val);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'newPage.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: 'courseTitle=' +val,
                success: function (response) {
                       location.href = "newPage.php";
                },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
                }

            }); 
        }
```

/*NEW PAGE*/

```
   <?php
         include ('config.php');
         @ob_start();
         session_start();

         if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){    
            $courseTitle = $_POST['courseTitle'];
            echo $courseTitle+"!!!";
            echo "<script type = 'text/javascript'>document.getElementById('#headerDiv').innerHTML = ".$courseTitle."</script>";
        }else{
            echo "NO POST!!";
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: In what way is this not working?  This approach is certainly *unconventional*, since making two requests to the same page seems pretty excessive.  How that page *responds* to these two separate requests is another story entirely as well.  What isn't actually working here?

Comment: I updated the question, I basically just do a request check and try to get the value from post.

Comment: Well, your AJAX request is a POST, but the redirect is going to be a GET.  And that second request isn't going to have the `courseTitle` value, you'd need to preserve that from the first request.  Honestly, this whole thing should *probably* just be one single request.  Why not just redirect with the `courseTitle` value on the query string?  Or skip JavaScript entirely and just use a form to post to the page?

Comment: The usual purpose of AJAX is to post to the server without reloading. If you want to reload the page, just do a normal form submission.